# Secondary_y range in a Pandas groupby function

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to change range of secondary Y axis in a simple example:

**MWE:**

```py
index=pd.date_range('2014-1-1 00:00:00', '2014-12-31 23:50:00', freq='1h')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(index),3).cumsum(axis=0),columns=['A','B','C'],index=index)

df_month = df.groupby(lambda x: x.month)
df_month.plot(secondary_y=['C'],mark_right=False)
```

In `groupby.plot` function I can only set ylim for left axis. How can I change the **right axis range** ?

I have also tried to loop over the key in `groupby`:

```
for key, group in df_month:
    ax = group[['A','B']].plot()
    fig= group[['C']].plot(secondary_y=True, ax=ax, mark_right=False)
```

using `ax2 = ax1.twinx()` variants but it did not work out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Pandas plot function returns an array of axes and you can get the right axis from from each axes with ax.right_ax.

```
axs = df_month.plot(secondary_y=['C'], mark_right=False)

for ax in axs:
    ax.right_ax.set_ylim((0,50)) # Set the y limits to 0 to 50
```